# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client -error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to redirect the page to another page . the first time when I send a post request it works fine but from second post request it gives me this error .

> Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent
> to the client

Every second time I send the post request it gives me the error.

**This is the code**

```
const find_doctor_and_update =(a , p) => {
console.log(a)
patients.findOneAndUpdate({name : a} , { $push :{ patients : p } } , {new : true})
.then(data => {
        return data;
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
}) };


router.post('/upload', authorize,  upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body)
    var pname = req.session.userid
    patient_detail.image_name = `${unique_id}-${req.file.originalname}`;
    patient_detail.pid = req.body.pid;
    patient_detail.name = req.body.name;
    patient_detail.age = req.body.age;
    patient_detail.bg = req.body.bg;
    prediction_file.stdin.write(`${unique_id}-${req.file.originalname}\n`);
    prediction_file.stdout.on('data', (output) => {
        if(output == 0){
            patient_detail.class = output;
            console.log('the output is here')

            find_doctor_and_update(pname, (patient_detail))
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                return res.redirect(`/viewpatient/${patient_detail.pid}`);
                
            })
            .catch(err => {
                 //this is the line where i get the error second time when I do post request
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
        console.log(`stdout: ${output}`);
    }) 
})
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Could you explain the flow to  me... I see you are not returning any promise but still you are using "then" block for "find_doctor_and_update". How is this not giving you any errors?

Comment: yes when i removed the "then" block it is showing another error that the promise is not handled

Comment: The flow is ->  when the post request is sent it stores the body in the patient_detail. then it goes to child process prediction file and then when gets the result back it goes to "find_doctor_and_update" function to update the database and then returns the updated data.  if there is no error in the function then it redirects to another page

Comment: This is why I don't understand. you are not returning any promise in "find_doctor_and_update" yet the "then" block works for you. 

Also, are you able to see console message from "console.log(a)" - the first line in "find_doctor_and_update" everytime you do a post request from postman??

Comment: yes i am able to see that

Comment: Could you try using this line of code
"patients.findOneAndUpdate({name : a} , { $push :{ patients : p } } , {new : true})" instead of 
"find_doctor_and_update(pname, (patient_detail))"

Answer (score 0):

I got the mistake I did . I tried to put the output function "prediction_file.stdout" inside the post method . Due to which it was looping back and even if I tried to do return it did not return.